high cpu load on idle
I'm running an android 10 rom (resurrection remix, no GAPPS) on top of which I have added magisk, zygisk-lsposed, and microg, and everything worked greatly for three years so far, so well that I felt no need to update.
But in the latest days I've noticed a battery drain, which is associated to a constant ~20% cpu load in idle. This is htop running from an adb -d shell:

I've checked that the set of few apps running in background is the same as usual (I use 'Battery Tool' app to automatically stop apps from running in background).
My question is, what could lead com.android.systemui and system_server to occupy all that cpu in idle?

The problem was due to a bug in adaway:
https://github.com/AdAway/AdAway/issues/4112
